# IllegalStateException for getRequestDispatcher

Tags: jsf, servlets

```
 if (requestURI.contains("apple") && requestURI.endsWith("xhtml")) {
    if (session == null || session.getAttribute("emid") == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("login.xhtml");
    } else {
        String param = request.getParameter("pname");
        String cp = request.getContextPath();
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        response.setHeader("Location", cp + "/apple/" + param);
    }
}

if (requestURI.contains("apple") && !requestURI.endsWith("xhtml")) {
    if (session == null || session.getAttribute("emid") == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("login.xhtml");
    } else {
            String ss[] = requestURI.split("/");
            String param = ss[ss.length-1];
            request.getRequestDispatcher("apple.xhtml?pname="+param).forward(arg0, arg1);
    }
}
    arg2.doFilter(arg0, arg1); //line 70
```

The above code is in the doFilter block.

What I'm trying to accomplish?
1) rewrite URLs with .xhtml extensions i.e. example.com/apple.xhtml?pname=ipod into something like this example.com/apple/ipod.
2) If session is null, the apple.xhtml page redirects to login.xhtml.

Task 2 is accomplished.

For some reasons, the rewrite isn't working because the line hsr.getRequestDispatcher("apple.xhtml?pname="+param).forward(arg0, arg1) throws "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed" exception. What am i doing wrong?

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:456)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:805)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:454)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.service(DefaultServlet.java:434)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at pcf.CleanUrls.doFilter(CleanUrls.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: If you have to explain what the variables are, then it's a clear sign that their name must be changed. How about `session`, `request` and `response`? Doesn't it make everything more readable? Also, when asking about an exception, always post the complete and exact exception stack trace.

Comment: hs is HttpSession object, hsr is HttpServletRequest object, hsrs = HttpServletResponse object and uri is string that contains Servlet Request URI

Comment: Read my comment again. I understand what those are, but you wouldn't have to tell us that if you named your variables correctly. `hs` and `hsr` don't mean anything. `session` and `request` do mean something. So use `session` and `request` instead. Make your code readable.

Comment: Why not use prettyfaces instead of reinventing the wheel? And I don't see any jsf in the stacktrace...

Comment: @Kukeltje: You're right! I've begun using prettyfaces. It's a great library